# Unable to pause videojs on load if autoplay is enabled

Tags: javascript, autoplay

this is my first question in stackoverflow so pardon me for mistakes.

I've been trying to create a simple CMS using videojs in which user could upload their video and customize their attributes (eg: autoplay, loop and controls).

When they change the attributes I will automatically recreate the whole tags and reinitialized it. I did this so it gave the correct preview especially on firefox since user will upload mp4 and firefox will give the "not supported" warning sign if I did not reinitialize it (videojs will automatically converts into flash).

Now the problem is when user checked the "autoplay" attributes because when I initialize the video it will automatically plays and I don't want that kind of behavior in the CMS (though I want that behavior in the published site).

I've been trying to pause the player once it was ready but it still plays.

My hypothesis is that the command to pause was fired before the command to play from the autoplay attributes.

This is the html tag used for this

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls width="640" height="264" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.jpg" autoplay preload="auto" data-setup="{}"> 
   <source type="video/mp4" src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4"> 
</video>
```

And this is the one I used to initialize and pause the video

```
   _V_(example_video_1).ready( function() {
       var myplayer = this;
       myplayer.pause(); 
   });
```

Any idea? Help is greatly appreciated. Worst case if all else fails I could use different tags for the preview and published site (no autoplay for the preview). I create a fiddle for this : http://jsfiddle.net/F8JhL/2/

EDIT: I noticed that sometimes the pause event really works though not automatically (about 1 to 2 second after the video plays) but more often it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I find the same issue when using version 4.1.0 of videojs. When I upgrade to version 5.1.0 this conflict is missing.

You could download the latest version at https://github.com/videojs/video.js/releases

So I think this bug has been fix (but I can't find the commit revision for this fix).